# Chef splits 'execute' command on multiple lines

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-ebs

Trying to create a cookbook to attach an EBS volume to an instance.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04 running inside AWS EC2 with credentials passed via an IAM role.

At some point I have a block as follows:

```
if do_attach
  execute 'attach_ebs_vol' do
    command "aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id #{volume_id} --instance-id #{instance_id} --device #{ebs_device}"
    action :run
  end
end
```

However when I actually go to run it, it seems `chef` is splitting the command into two separate lines?  This is what the output looks like:

```
[2018-07-12T03:37:28+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[attach_ebs_vol] (aws_attach_ebs_vol::default line 69) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-08a69721ee5ffe615 --instance-id i-0342cc9794decd206
 --device /dev/sdf ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --device is required
sh: 2: --device: not found
---- End output of aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-08a69721ee5ffe615 --instance-id i-0342cc9794decd206
 --device /dev/sdf ----
Ran aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-08a69721ee5ffe615 --instance-id i-0342cc9794decd206
 --device /dev/sdf returned 127
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Pretty new to both `chef` and `ruby` and haven't found anything that would point me in the right direction in documentation.

I've initially tried setting the command as a variable like so:

```
if do_attach
  attach_cmd = "aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id #{volume_id} --instance-id #{instance_id} --device #{ebs_device}"
  execute 'attach_ebs_vol' do
    command attach_cmd
    action :run
  end
end
```

However it doesn't really make a difference. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where are you getting that instance_id value from? It probably has a newline in it so you would need instance_id.strip or similar.

Comment: Awesome that was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to /u/coderanger's comment above!

I was getting `instance_id` from ec2metadata as follows:

```
instance_id = shell_out("ec2metadata --instance-id").stdout
```

Adding `.strip` fixed it:

```
instance_id = shell_out("ec2metadata --instance-id").stdout.strip
```

Comment: As an addendum, we track that for you already via Ohai. `node['ec2']['instance_id']` should work.